# Dojo: how to remove comma from value

Tags: dojo

I have this Dijit number spinner:

```html
<div class="extra_field hide_on_load form_action_fy">
    <label>Action Fiscal Year</label>
    <input name="form_action_fy" id="form_action_fy"
        data-dojo-type="dijit.form.NumberSpinner" 
        data-dojo-props="
            value:@ViewBag.fy,
            smallDelta:1, 
            largeDelta:1, 
            constraints:{min:2010,max:2020,places:0}"
    />
</div>
```

After this input loses focus, a comma is added. How do I prevent this comma from showing? That is, I don't want 2,011 but rather 2011.

Thanks!
Eric

Comment: Change your locale to Brazil so you get a period instead :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simple answer is to add `pattern:'#'` to your constraints object.

The pattern property allows you to specify how you want your numeric data to be displayed.  [Here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/numbersDates.html#number-pattern-characters) is a link to dojo's reference on number patterns.  The whole page is pretty informative on formatting numbers.

Your example should end up looking something like this:

```html
<div class="extra_field hide_on_load form_action_fy">
    <label>Action Fiscal Year</label>
    <input name="form_action_fy" id="form_action_fy"
        data-dojo-type="dijit.form.NumberSpinner" 
        data-dojo-props="
            value:2011,
            smallDelta:1, 
            largeDelta:1, 
            constraints:{min:2010,max:2020,places:0,pattern:'#'}"
    />
</div>
```

Comment: The link takes you to deprecated documentation.  Here is the version as specified for Dojo 1.7, http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/quickstart/numbersDates.html#number-pattern-characters