# Is there a way to remove a comma from dojo's NumberSpinner?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dojo: how to remove comma from value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996427/dojo-how-to-remove-comma-from-value)

For some reason, my NumberSpinner always displays numbers above 999 as comma-separated (1,001). Is there a way to make that spinner display the non-comma separated value to the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `replace()` method to remove the commas and replace them with an empty string.

```
var number = "1,001";
console.log(number.replace(/\,/g, ""));
```

Another way I found ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996427/dojo-how-to-remove-comma-from-value)) is to add the following to your constraints object

```
pattern:'#'
```

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I do for getting the value from the control, but is there a way to fix the value that is displayed to the user?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Dojo so I don't know how the number is displayed to the user, but I presume you can just pass the new replaced value instead, can't you? A link would be nice since I'm unfamiliar

Comment: Here's the link - http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/NumberSpinner.html . When you edit the value, it is displayed as `1050`, but when you click away, it changes to `1,050` - which could be fine, in some locales it is used to separate magnitudes.

Comment: Well, if you don't have direct access to the source of the function, can you just do a simple `onchange` event that changes the value?

Comment: Well, maybe I could - but firstly, it's not so simple - dojo provides this functionality as packed widgets, so to change string value directly, I'll need to do dirty and crumbesome hacks. And secondly, I hoped for some simple way.

Comment: Where does dojo get the NumberSpinner fuction from?

Comment: From Dijit Widget framework.

Comment: @Rogach - I've updated my post with the proper way to do it